# equal recognition in quadratic equation matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I have the next code of the quadratic equation:

```
if b^2-4*a*c<0 
    disp('No real solutions')
elseif a==0
    x=-c/b
elseif abs(b)==sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)
   w = b+sign(b)*sqrt(b^2-4*a*c);
   x1 = -w/(2*a)
   x2 = -(2*c)/w
else
   x1=(-2*c)/(b+sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))
   x2=(-2*c)/(b-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))
end
```

But Matlab doesn't recognize me when `b` is equal to `sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)` in some cases, such `x^2 -100000001+1`, but the equality is true: `abs(-100000001)= sqrt((-100000001)^2-4*1*1)`.

What should I change because Matlab recognize me equality in these extreme cases?

Comment: `abs(-100000001)` and `sqrt((-100000001)^2-4*1*1)` is not equal.

Comment: sqrt((-100000001)^2-4*1*1) in matlab is equal to 1.000000010000000e+08, that this is 100000001.00000, has all the correct significant digits, but I already corrected the method, I established a bound on the sentence and matlab already understood a number exactly equal or a similar number

Comment: No, it's not equal. The difference is `-0.00000001999999980000000399999990851...` (calculated using mupad)

Comment: @Daniel or possibly even more with standard precision - for `abs(-100000001) - sqrt((-100000001)^2-4*1*1)`, Octave gives me `ans = 2.9802e-008`

Comment: @Notlikethat: Mupad vpa has a higher precision than octave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Ali: It's not a duplicate. Both numbers aren't equal.

Comment: @Daniel OK, so on the top of that, the question is also wrong as the numbers aren't equal even in exact arithmetic. One more reason to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the finite numerical precision, Matlab may introduce some small errors. Thus, it is usually better to include some tolerance. For example,

```
tol = 1e-5;
...
if abs(b-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))<tol,
% It is considered that both are equal
...
end
```